# How do I correct my curve deformed array?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]
[image]

I want to join the ends I have fiddled with the numbers on the array modifier's relative offset options but cant seem to make the ends fit together.

I have also tried fiddling with the curve shape.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong. Add a screenshot of your mesh in edit mode, and I think I'll be able to tell.

Comment: here is the mesh in edit mode

Comment: I'm not seeing anything different in the new image. Are you sure you've tabbed into edit mode for the mesh, not the curve?

Comment: Have you tried to scale the curve a bit?

Answer (score 7):

You may scale the *curve* (<kbd>S</kbd>) holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> button to precisely close the object's ends.
[image]

You can also select the *curve*, go to *curve data* header and check the ***Stretch*** and ***Bounds Clamp*** checkboxes located in the *Shape* panel.
[image]